# Bool is changing and staying the same in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean, coroutine

I have a relatively simple game in Unity3D that has some zombies moving towards a central base and attacking it until it's health reaches 0. The attacks are run in a co-routing to create a delay between them. The problem is have here is that once you kill an enemy the co-routine keeps on running. I've assigned a bool isAttacking to the Enemy script which is initialized to false, set to true when the enemy is attacking and set back to false again when the enemy is dead. The coroutine that controls the attacks shouldn't run if isAttacking is set to false but for some reason it still carries on running even if the enemy is dead. Whats really confusing me is that if I run the game, wait for the coroutine to start, kill the enemy and then manually untick 'isAttacking' in the inspector then the co-routine stops running. I've included both the Enemy & Base scripts, any help is appreciated.

BASE SCRIPT

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Base : MonoBehaviour {

public float Health = 100f;
public float AttackSpeed = 2f;

//VOID AWAKE - START . contains getcomponent code
public Enemy enemy;
void awake(){
    enemy = GetComponent<Enemy>();
}
//VOID AWAKE - END

//If enemy touches the base 
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col){
    Debug.Log ("Base touched");
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy"){
        enemy.isAttacking = true;
        if(Health > 0f){
            Debug.Log ("Enemy attacking base");
            StartCoroutine("enemyAttack");
        }else{
            enemy.isAttacking = false;
        }
    }
}

//Coroutine that deals damage
public IEnumerator enemyAttack(){
    while(Health > 0f){
        if(enemy.isAttacking == true){
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
            Health -= Enemy.Damage;
            Debug.Log ("Base health at: " + Health);
        }else{
            yield break;
        }
    }
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    //Load Lose Screen when Base health reaches 0
    if (Health <= 0){
        Application.LoadLevel("Lose Screen");
    }
}
}
```

ENEMY SCRIPT

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour {

public static float Damage = 10.0f;
public float Health = 20.0f;

public Transform target;
public float Speed;

public bool isAttacking = false;

//If the player collides with the enemy
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        Debug.Log("Player hits enemy");
        Health -= PlayerController.Damage;
        Debug.Log("Enemy health at: " + Health);
    }
}


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    //Destroy the enemy if it's health reaches 0
    if(Health <= 0){
        isAttacking = false;
        Debug.Log ("Is attacking: " + isAttacking);
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        Debug.Log ("Enemy Destroyed!");
    }

    //Constantly move the enemy towards the centre of the gamespace (where the base is)
    float step = Speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
}
}
```

EDIT
Currently the problem is solved except for the fact that if the player touches the base then all enemies stop attacking. I've updated the code to show it in its current state.
BASE SCRIPT
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

```
public class Base : MonoBehaviour {

public float Health = 100f;
public float AttackSpeed = 2f;

//VOID AWAKE - START . contains getcomponent code
public Enemy enemy;
void awake(){
    enemy = GetComponent<Enemy>();
}
//VOID AWAKE - END

//If enemy touches the base 
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col){
    Debug.Log ("Base touched");
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy" && Health > 0f){
        enemy.isAttacking = true;
        Debug.Log ("Enemy attacking base");
        StartCoroutine("enemyAttack");
    }
    else{
        enemy.isAttacking = false;
    }
}

//Coroutine that deals damage
public IEnumerator enemyAttack(){
    while(Health > 0f){
        if(enemy.isAttacking == true){
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
            Health -= Enemy.Damage;
            Debug.Log ("Base health at: " + Health);
        }else{
            yield break;
        }
    }
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    //Load Lose Screen when Base health reaches 0
    if (Health <= 0){
        Application.LoadLevel("Lose Screen");
    }

}
}
```

ENEMY SCRIPT

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour {

public static float Damage = 10.0f;
public float Health = 20.0f;

public Transform target;
public float Speed;

public bool isAttacking = false;

//If the player collides with the enemy
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        Debug.Log("Player hits enemy");
        Health -= PlayerController.Damage;
        Debug.Log("Enemy health at: " + Health);
    }
}


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    //Destroy the enemy if it's health reaches 0
        if(Health <= 0){
            isAttacking = false;
            Debug.Log ("Is attacking: " + isAttacking);
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            Debug.Log ("Enemy Destroyed!");
        }

    //Constantly move the enemy towards the centre of the gamespace (where the base is)
    float step = Speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
}
}
```

Comment: So your main problem is that the un-dead zombies won't die?

Comment: no, the zombies die. The main problem is that when the zombies die the bool isAttacking doesn't change to false. This means that the coroutine dealing damage to the base keeps running continually, even if there aren't any enemies

Comment: Comment on your edit. That really should be put as another question...

Comment: I've posted a new question

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you add a enemy.isAttacking = false; to the outer if statement?

```
//If enemy touches the base 
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col){
    Debug.Log ("Base touched");
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy"){
        enemy.isAttacking = true;
        if(Health > 0f){
            Debug.Log ("Enemy attacking base");
            StartCoroutine("enemyAttack");
        }
        else{
            enemy.isAttacking = false;
        }

    }
    else{ 
        enemy.isAttacking = false;
        }
}
```

EDIT

In the first if statement you could have

```
if(col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy" && Health > 0f){
...
```

Then maybe not even have the inner if else?

EDIT

For the zombies not dying use a while loop like

```
    // Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    while(isAttacking == true)
    {
        if(Health <= 0)
        {
            Debug.Log ("Is attacking: " + isAttacking);
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            Debug.Log ("Enemy Destroyed!");
            isAttacking = false;
        }

        //Constantly move the enemy towards the centre of the gamespace (where the base is)
        float step = Speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I forgot to resolve the first if statement. It's a lot closer to working how I want it to now. Now isAttacking switches to false as soon as the player attacks the enemy once (the enemy only dies after the player attacks it twice).

Comment: glad its helped. easy mistake to make and you learn from your mistakes :)

Comment: There is a small problem with that solution though, now if the player touches the base isAttacking switches to false

Comment: I've removed the inner if else but the bool still changes when the player touches the base and not when the enemy is killed. I'll keep looking!

Comment: adding a while loop is stopping the enemy from being destroyed at all, the enemy health just continually decreases

Comment: The zombies get destroyed correctly when their health reaches 0 but isAttacking doesn't change to false in the editor. It changes in code but not in the Inspector, as such the coroutine keeps running. If i manually untick the bool isAttacking then the coroutine stops running.

Comment: in the whiles if statement, put isAttacking = false; at the bottom. I think the destroy command is not running at all. sorry, il edit the post

Comment: I've updated the main question to show the current problem & code